# Логика и назначение Product trait

Tags: scala

Столкнулся с проблемой непонимания как работает trait Product.
Пример:

```
List(1,2).productIterator.toList
```

Возвращает

```
List[Any] = List(1, List(2))
```

Покопавшись в документации пока не смог найти ответа на вопрос почему 2-ой элемент возвращается как List(2) а не просто 2.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала объясню что такое `List`, потом объясню как работает `productIterator`.

И так `List` - это абстрактный класс, а значит создать его экземпляр нельзя. То что выглядит как `List` - на самом деле один из его наследников. У класса `List` два наследника - кейс-класс `::` и кейс-объект `Nil`.

Давай посмотрим на их реализацию:

```
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
  override def tail : List[B] = tl
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}

case object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
  override def isEmpty = true
  override def head: Nothing =
    throw new NoSuchElementException("head of empty list")
  override def tail: List[Nothing] =
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("tail of empty list")
  // Removal of equals method here might lead to an infinite recursion similar to IntMap.equals.
  override def equals(that: Any) = that match {
    case that1: scala.collection.GenSeq[_] => that1.isEmpty
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

То, что `Nil` - это пустой список, знают многие, поэтому рассмотрим кейс-класс `::`. Как видишь у него два поля - `head` и `tl`. Заметь что `head`- это один элемент, а `tl` - коллекция(`List`).
Т.е. когда мы пишем

```
List(1)
```

на самом деле создается такой кейс-класс:

```
::(1, Nil)
::(head = 1, tl = Nil)//тоже самое с именованными параметрами
```

А когда ты создаешь `List(1, 2)` на самом деле создается такое:

```
::(1, ::(2, Nil))

::(head = 1, tl = ::(2, Nil)) //тоже самое с именованными параметрами
```

Обрати внимание на то, что второй параметр имеет тип `List`, а значит какого бы ты наследника не передал (`::` или `Nil`) - виден он будет как `List`.

Теперь про `productIterator`, этот метод возвращает итератор на аргументы класса.
В нашем случае у объекта `Nil` - нету аргументов, а у класса `::` есть всего два аргумента - `head` и `tl`. Их значения ты и видишь.

P.S. А метод `productIterator` у них есть - благодаря тому, что они кейс-класс и кейс-объект.

Полезные материалы:

- http://www.alessandrolacava.com/blog/scala-case-classes-in-depth/
- http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html
- исходники Scala